# How to check if an element exists on the page in Playwright.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser-automation, playwright

I am using playwright.js to write a script for https://target.com, and on the page where you submit shipping information, it will provide the option to use a saved address if you have gone through the checkout process previously on that target account.

I would like to enter fresh shipping information every time I run the script, so I must have playwright click delete if it exists on the page, and then enter the shipping information.

The function that is shown below works to click delete, but then it times out at `if (await page.$$("text='Delete'") != [])` rather than executing the `else` part of the function.

How can I rewrite this function so that it simply checks if the element (selector: `text='Delete'`) exists, and clicks it if it does, and executes the filling part of the function if it doesn't?

```js
  async function deliveryAddress() {
    if (await page.$$("text='Delete'") != []) {
      await page.click("text='Delete'", {force:true})
      await deliveryAddress()
    } else {
      await page.focus('input#full_name')
      await page.type('input#full_name', fullName, {delay: delayms});
      await page.focus('input#address_line1')
      await page.type('input#address_line1', address, {delay: delayms});
      await page.focus('input#zip_code')
      await page.type('input#zip_code', zipCode, {delay: delayms});
      await page.focus('input#mobile')
      await page.type('input#mobile', phoneNumber, {delay: delayms});
      await page.click("text='Save & continue'", {force:true})
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can't compare arrays like this in JavaScript, you can check array length or use `if (await page.$('text=Delete')) {}`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have two main options:

```js
const deletes = await page.$$("text='Delete'");
if (deletes) {
    // ...
}
```

or

```js
const deletes = await page.$$("text='Delete'");
if (deletes.length) {
    // ...
}
```

I'd personally leave the `$$` command outside the if statement for readability, but that might me only me.

It also seems you have only one element with attribute text with value "Delete" on the page since you're not doing anything with the array that `$$` returns. If so, you might use [`$`](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.6.2&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=pageselector):

```js
const del = await page.$("text='Delete'");
if (del) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `const deletes = await page.$$("text='Delete'");
if (deletes) {` doesn't work--`page.$$` returns an array, and arrays are always truthy even if there's nothing in them. I suggest removing that.

Answer (score 34):

```
await page.isVisible("text='Delete'")
```

maybe this is the one you're looking for.

From [the `.isVisible()` documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-is-visible):

> Returns whether the element is visible. **`selector` that does not match any elements is considered not visible.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: was the correct answerer for me.
thanks.
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-is-visible

Comment: Although this answer is correct, PlayWright recommends using the `isVisible()` function on the locator instead. For me that makes more sense since I have a separate class returning locators. That way I only need to define my locators once and I can reuse them anywhere.

Comment: Why you should *NOT* rely anymore on isVisible? See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75901956

Answer (score 31):

```js
await expect(page.locator(".MyClass")).toHaveCount(0)
```

Comment: Notice that the question is "how to check if an element exists", doesn't mean to actually verify that an element is present... and this is the case.
This answer will cause an exception and I am sure that's not the goal of the question.
A lot of times, there is only a need to see if something is there or not, and then decide what to do based on the result of the check... and this is the reason for the question.

Comment: Also note that `expect` is not available when using the [playwright library](https://playwright.dev/docs/library) (as opposed to the playwright test runner). You might use some method of `locator`, like [`waitFor()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-wait-for) or [`count()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-count).

Answer (score 23):

Usualy this can help in lot of situations, when checking element presence.

```
if(await page.locator(your_selector).count()>0)
```

Comment: For how much time is it going to wait to return the count()? Would it return immediately or wait for the timeout set in the playwright config? Because in either case, it wouldn't be of any help as I am trying to click on the element only if its visible within 3 seconds of page load completion.

Comment: Use web assertion as recommended by playwright in recent versions- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75901956

Comment: @VishalAggarwal Assertions don't work when you're writing stuff besides test cases. https://playwright.dev/docs/library#key-differences

Comment: @DexieTheSheep can you explain, what  you mean by that?

Comment: @VishalAggarwal From what I can tell, `expect()` isn't part of the Playwright Library (`playwright`), and it's only in  Playwright Test (`@playwright/test`), so if you're writing code that exists as its own module instead of a test case, you need to use this method. Interestingly, this isn't an issue for the .NET or Python versions, but I can't check the docs for Java (says there isn't a page for it).

Comment: If you are writing stuff beyond test cases , you are still free to use any third party assertion libraries which are even bigger than web assertions like Jest.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal Playwright is used for scraping and automating websites, which doesn't use the `@playwight/test` library. There isn't a need for any assertions or test framework at all when you're using it for scraping and automation purposes. It's just a plain Node script.

Answer (score 9):

```
try {
  await page.waitForSelector(selector, { timeout: 5000 })
  // ...`enter code here`
} catch (error) {`enter code here`
  console.log("The element didn't appear.")
}
```

from - https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1149#issuecomment-434302298

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple code to check the visibility of an element and take the necessary action.

Below code check for the visibility of an element and click on the same element if element is visible on DOM.

```
if(await page.locator('Your selector').isVisible()){
  await page.locator("Your selector").click()
}
```

Even if the locator is not visible on the page, it does not throw any exception or error.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is:

```
await expect(page.locator('.somethingdoesnotexistYET')).toBeVisible()
```

Use [web assertion](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-be-visible) as recommended  by playwright as best practice:

Per [Playwright Docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-be-visible)(v1.20):

This will ensure that Locator points to an attached and visible DOM element.

Reference:https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/18394

Comment: toBeVisible retrun tipe is Promise<void>, it does not return a boolean, therefore if statement will never be triggered below

Comment: @VishalAggarwal felsher's spelling does not change the fact that your code does not work. Maybe cut down on the snark until you understand what Promise<Void> means.  `if (await locator.isVisible()) {}` is the correct solution (as in the most up-voted answer).

Comment: @VishalAggarwal Which version of Playwright are you using?  When I type your code into VS Code I get the error "an expression of type 'void' can not be tested for truthiness."  When I look at the code for `toBeVisible` it is declared to return `Promise<Void>` so it will never resolve to a boolean.  As far as I am aware all the `toBeX` web assertions throw exceptions and the `isX` methods return a boolean.

Comment: Yes , you are right. Thanks for pointing out. I updated the answer.

Comment: Still this answer is valid, more updated and better compared to other outdated answers which does not reflect the recent recommendations from the playwright docs.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal Not the downvoter, and the answer is useful, but OP isn't asking about `@playwright/test`, just Playwright. Outside of testing, it's sometimes necessary to use a non-retrying conditional check.

Answer (score -1):

```
await expect(page).toHaveSelectorCount('.floorNav__modal', 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it handles all the scenarios with error handling -

```
async isSelectorExists(selector: string) {
  return await this._page.$(selector).catch(() => null) !== null;
}
```

Invalid selector - return false

```
console.log(await isSelectorExists('$'))
```

Valid selector and exists - return true

```
console.log(await isSelectorExists('body'))
```

Valid selector but not exists - return false

```
console.log(await isSelectorExists('h1'))
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to check if an element exits is:

```
if selector_exits(page, 'div[aria-label="Next"]'):
    print('yeah it exits')

def selector_exists(page, selector, timeout=3000):
    try:
        element = page.locator(selector).is_visible(timeout=timeout)
        return element
    except:
        return False
```

*Note: this is a python based approach. Convert in your desired language.*