# How to check if an element is in the document with playwright?

Tags: node.js, playwright

I want to test if an element had been rendered. So I want expect that if is present. Is there a command for this?

```
await page.goto(‘<http://localhost:3000/>');
const logo = await page.$(‘.logo’)

// expect(logo.toBeInDocument())
```

Comment: You can check if `logo` is null

Comment: @hardkoded but logo seems to be a promise

Comment: You are awaiting page.$. That shouldn't be a promise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make CONDITIONAL STATEMENTS using SELECTORS on PLAYWRIGHT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69206796/how-to-make-conditional-statements-using-selectors-on-playwright)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if an element exists on the page in Playwright.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64784781/how-to-check-if-an-element-exists-on-the-page-in-playwright-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you query one element with `page.$()`, you can simply use:

```js
const logo = await page.$('.logo');
if (logo) {

}
```

Similarly if you query multiple elements with `page.$$()`:

```js
const logo = await page.$$('.logo');
if (logo) {

}
```

Since this example returns (after awaiting) an array of element handles, you can also use property `length` in the condition:

```js
const logo = await page.$$('.logo');
if (logo.length) {

}
```

The key in all these examples is to await the promise that `page.$()` and `page.$$()` return.

Comment: Wondering where to throw an error if the if-statement doe not match.

Answer (score 6):

Since the use of ElementHandle (page.$(), page.$$()) is discouraged by the Playwright Team, you could use the Locator object and the count() method:

```
expect(await page.locator('data-testid=exists').count()).toBeTruthy();
expect(await page.locator('data-testid=doesnt-exist').count()).toBeFalsy();
```

If you want to check if the element is rendered (I assume you mean visible) you could use the [toBeVisible](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#locator-assertions-to-be-visible) assertion:

```
await expect(page.locator('data-testid=is-visible')).toBeVisible();
```