# Check if element is visible in Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm using Playwright 1.15.2 for testing and facing a problem with elements' visibility. I want to check if a modal is visible on screen so I can close it. The modal starts with `display:none` and turns into `display:block`. Also, the modal informs incorrectness in form data so it may or may not appear (i.e. I can't `waitForSelector`).

Currently, I have a code similar to the following:

```js
const myModal = await page.$("#modal");
if (await myModal.isVisible()) {
  await page.waitForSelector('#modal > .modal-dialog > .modal-content > .modal-footer > .btn-close');
  await page.click('#modal > .modal-dialog > .modal-content > .modal-footer > .btn-close');
}
```

I've also tried:

```js
const myModal = await page.$("#modal:visible");
if (myModal) {
...
```

Using `page.$("text=modal title >> visible=true")` or switching `page.$` to `page.locator` (with all the aforementioned selectors) also didn't work.

The accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64784781/how-to-check-if-an-element-exists-on-the-page-in-playwright-js) didn't work as well.

Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: did you try  await expect(yourModalLocator).toBeVisible(); ?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75901956

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`page.$("text=modal title >> visible=true")` does not wait until the element is on the DOM and visible.

you need to use:

`await expect(page.locator("text=modal title")).toBeVisible()`

see here: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#expectlocatortobevisibleoptions

Comment: Is there a reason you need both `visible=true` and `isVisible()`?

Comment: @CathalMacDonnacha No.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by using `waitFor` with different `state`

```
 constructor(page: Page) {
        this.page = page;
        this.myElement = page.locator('div.myElement');
     }
 async isMyElementVisible() {
        await this.myElement.waitFor({ state: 'visible' });
        return await this.myElement.isVisible();
    }

 async isMyElementHidden() {
        await this.myElement.waitFor({ state: 'hidden' });
        return await this.myElement.isHidden();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways to check element is NOT visible (check waitForSelector [options](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector)):

```
await page.waitForSelector('.btn', { state: 'detached' });
```

or

```
expect(await page.$$('.btn')).toHaveLength(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to do this:

1. Check if a locator is visible

- https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-is-visible

```js
const visible = await page.getByRole('button').isVisible();
const isTextVisible = await page.locator(':text("Some text")').isVisible();
const isElementVisible = await page.locator('button').isVisible();
```

2. Check if an element is visible

- https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-is-visible
- https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-query-selector

```js
await elementHandle.isVisible();
```

I find the locator API to be more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function checkElement(locator: Locator){
    return new Promise<void>(resolve =>{
        locator.waitFor({state:"visible"})
        .then(async ()=>{
            // do something when visible
        })
        .catch( async ()=>{
            // do something when hidden
        })
        .finally( ()=>{
            // do something regardless of visible or hidden
            resolve();
        })
    })
}
```