# How to quickly find out if an element exists in a page or not using Playwright Python

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I have this code to locate a link, using python playwright:

```
nfo_link = page.locator('the xpath').get_attribute('href')
nfo_link = 'https://somesite.com' + nfo_link
logger_play.info('nfo_link: %s', nfo_link)
```

it works fine if present, but if not present gives an error:

```
waiting for selector
```

i have tried:

```
 if (page.locator('the xpath').get_attribute('href')) == None:
       pass
 else:
       nfo_link = page.locator('the xpath').get_attribute('href')
```

and other code, but none seem to work, i want, if found good, if not move on, can someone point me to the right way?

Comment: Maybe you could add ```elem = page.locator('smt').wait_for()``` and ```elem.get_attribute('smt')```, if there's none, it will raise a timeout error.

Comment: but i don't want a timeout error(i have it now), but move on.

Comment: Then you could set your own timer, if the process exceeds a reasonable time, then you might assume the one you're searching doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript, you can use one of these options:

```js
const element = await page.$$("text='element'");
if (element) {
    // ...
}
```

or

```js
const element = await page.$$("text='element'");
if (element.length) {
    // ...
}
```

or

```js
await expect(page.locator(".MyClass")).toHaveCount(0)
```

Comment: The code is not asyinc and Js.

Comment: This question is about Python. This is purely JS. [How to check if an element exists on the page in Playwright.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64784781/how-to-check-if-an-element-exists-on-the-page-in-playwright-js) is the JS version of the thread.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`query_selector`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-query-selector) to verify if an element is matching your selector. If no elements match the selector it returns `null`.

Use

```
page.query_selector('selector') != None
```

or

```
page.query_selector('selector') is not None
```

or just

```
page.query_selector('selector')
```

Comment: `None` in python is a singleton and checking should be done using `is` or `is not` and not the `==` or `!=` operators.

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap it in a `try...except` block so you don't have a blocking timeout error.

```py
try:
  // some selector that might fail
  page.locator("whatever")
except:
  print("Not today")

// Move on...
```

Comment: Page locator is always defined. It's not Selenium :)

Answer (score -4):

You have several options depending on particular needs;
If your element is not hidden you can use:

```
page.locator("your_locator").isVisible();
```

If it is hidden you can try with.

```
try{
page.waitForSelector("your_locator",{timeout:5000});}
catch(){
//element is not found do next
}
```