# How to check for element existence without getting an error in Playwright

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I only wish to check if this element exist, or to test that it is hidden or not.

```
def get_error_message(self):
    is_error_msg = not self.page.wait_for_selector(
        self.ERROR_MESSAGE, timeout=5000).is_hidden()
    return is_error_msg
```

The line with `wait_for_selector` throws an error is the element is hidden. But I just want to know if the element is hidden or not, I'm not expecting it to be visible or hidden all the time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to quickly find out if an element exists in a page or not using Playwright Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70770526/how-to-quickly-find-out-if-an-element-exists-in-a-page-or-not-using-playwright-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something called `element_handle.is_visible()` from [here](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-is-visible).

your code should look something like below.

```py
href_element = page.query_selector("a")
href_element.is_visible()
```