# Playwright: how to ensure an element does NOT exist?

Tags: node.js, playwright

I'm trying to use Playwright with Jest to automate some test about uploading a file in a Microsoft Teams channel.

This is what I have and works:

```
it('should upload a file', async () => {
    // Listen to file chooser popup and set file for upload
    page.on('filechooser', async (fileChooser) => {
        await fileChooser.setFiles('test-files/example.txt');
    });

    // wait for the content iframe to be loaded
    const contentFrame = page.frameLocator('[name="embedded-page-container"]');

    // @TODO here I would like to first make sure the file does not exist
    // 
    // How could I do that ???
    // 

    // upload file and check for existence in file list displayed
    await contentFrame.locator('button[name="Upload"]').click();
    await contentFrame.locator('button[name="Files"]').click();
    await contentFrame.locator('button:has-text("example.txt")').waitFor({ state: "visible" });
});
```

**The question:** How could I check that the file does not exist before ?
Basically how do I check that the `button:has-text("example.txt")` element which I wait to become visible at the last line, does **NOT** exist before the upload action ?

Thanks.

Comment: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#locator-assertions-to-be-hidden

Comment: I'm not talking about elements which exist but are *hidden*, I'm talking about elements which do *not* exist at all in the page...

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar with python instead of javascript, but it should be useful for you.

I defined my own function in a helper:

```
def my_own_wait_for_selector(page, selector, time_out):
    try:
        page.wait_for_selector(selector, timeout=time_out)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Then you can use it for knowing if your element is in the DOM or not and take a decision/flow based on that

```
if helper.my_own_wait_for_selector(page, "MySelector", 5000):
    #Whatever I want to do if element is there
else:
    #Whatever I want to do if element is NOT there
```

Comment: I'd post this in a Python thread, like [How to quickly find out if an element exists in a page or not using Playwright Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70770526/how-to-quickly-find-out-if-an-element-exists-in-a-page-or-not-using-playwright-p)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way:

```
await expect(page.locator('span:has-text("Generate PDF")')).toBeVisible() // Just for context of how to do the opposite
await expect(page.locator('span:has-text("Generate ePub")')).not.toBeVisible()
await expect(page.locator('span:has-text("Generate Docx")')).not.toBeVisible()
```

Source: [Github issue outlines solution](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/discussions/10420?sort=top)