# Playwright checking the text of a locator and replacing values

Tags: typescript, function, if-statement, playwright

i have the following block of code that checks if the field with id=streetNumber contains either the values 23 or 45 and adds a value depending on what it finds

```
async function replace(page: Page) {
    if (await page.locator('id=streetNumber'), { hasText: "23"}) {
        await page.locator('id=streetNumber').fill('45');
    }
    else {
        await page.locator('id=streetNumber').fill('23');
    }
}
```

My problem is that every time it fills in 45, even if instructed to fill in 45 only if 23 is already there and to fill in 23 if anything else is there. What is going wrong here ?

Comment: The code doesn't make sense. Locators are always truthy, so the bottom branch is unreachable. Generally, you don't want to use conditions in Playwright tests, so I suspect a better fundamental solution to whatever problem you're facing is available, if you don't mind [stepping back and providing context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if an element exists on the page in Playwright.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64784781/how-to-check-if-an-element-exists-on-the-page-in-playwright-js)

Comment: The problem i am having is that i have an input field with the attribute id=streetNumber that has a value in it. I am trying to test the edit function, so basically if the value present is 23, i want to enter the new value of 45. If the value not 23, then i want to enter the value 23 and then save the value but every time i run this code it is always the else that gets executed. Something in the if is either not correct or not possible at all.

Comment: I explained why this is happening and linked to a thread showing how to do it. Did you read that? I understand what you're trying to do, but it's discouraged to use `if`s in tests. Usually, you'd test an edit function by punching in one value, then the next, without an `if`.